# Why Does $ Come Before the Number But % Comes After it?

Tags: grammar, symbols

Let's look at these two sentences:

> Color blindness affects 8% of men.
>
> That sandwich costs $8.

So why, when using the percent symbol do we put it after the word, but with money we place it before the word?

Comment: I'm nit-picking a bit, but '%' is not a unit of measure- it denotes a ratio multiplied by 100 for convenience, and represents the /100 required to yield the actual ratio. Variants have appeared before the number in Italian, for example.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany so just like Joe Z, said it is pretty much based off of where the language originated. Interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is mostly just local convention.

In some places in the world, they do put the dollar sign after the number, e.g. in French in Québec:

> Ce sandwich coûte 7,50 $.
>
> *That sandwich costs $7.50.*